# Output variable without using <Text> tag

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to ask for some advise. I am new to React so I don't know how things work around here. So I want my variable to output this: < Text>Zlin</ Text> < br> (in code: lokace +='' + mesta[i] + '< /Text>' + "\n" ). How do I archieve this? It always wants to be in < Text> when I call for it in return().

I will remake this to output cards that generate in this loop so I can't use < Text>.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Card, CardTitle, CardContent, CardAction, CardButton, CardImage } from 'react-native-material-cards';
var mesta = ['Zlin','Praha','Ostrava','Brno']


    var cardBeg = ['<Text>']
    var cardEnd = ['</Text>']
    var lokace = []
    for (var i=0; i < mesta.length; i++)
    {
        lokace +='<Text>' + mesta[i] + '</Text>' + "\n"
    }


export default function Primary({ navigation })
{
    return(
        <ScrollView style=
            {{ 
                flex: 1,
            }}>
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: "violet", borderRadius: 20, alignItems: 'center', margin: 5, padding: 10}}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 26, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                    Swag
                    </Text>
                    {lokace}   //this doesnt work
                    <Text>{lokace}</Text>  //this does, but I dont want to output only text and how I said, I will later be outputting whole tables.
                    
            </View>    
            
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop through data in React, you would generally use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

So you would just need to map through your `mesta` array within the JSX. Here's a simplified version of what you need to do:

```
function Primary() {
  return (
    <ScrollView
      <View>
        <Text>Swag</Text>
        {mesta.map(item => (
          <Text>{item}</Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

Also, I'd advise against using `var` when declaring variables. Using `let` or `const` are now the best practices. The general rule is to use `let` when you want to declare a mutable value and `const` for an immutable one (but it's more of a personal choice!).

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i get your question coorectly, but maybe this is kindof what you want to do:

instead of `{lokace}`

do

`{mesta.map((m) => <Text> m </Text> )}`

and delete the for loop